# How Can I Set hour and minute on datepicker jquery,it shouldnt be writable too long

Tags: jquery, datepicker

When you want to broke format hh:mm jquery datetimepicker, able to do it. But I want it to block. if you write hh:mm like 1231313:98090909099 it shouldnt be allowed. How can I set time format like 'hh:mm'.

Thanks, Regards

Comment: Which datetimepicker are you using?

Comment: There is no time picker. There are 3rd party modules and plugins, but you can't do time with the jquery date picker, so what are you using?

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/
I used first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I provided  set maxlength attribute for datepicker. for example :

```
$('#datepickerFrom').attr("maxlength", "10");
```

so it is not allowed for too long charachters.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a readonly input and configure datepicker to get only hour and minutes using datetimepicker, an extension of the datepicker plugin:

```
$('#date').datetimepicker({
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm'
});

<input name="date" id="date" readonly="readonly" />
```

more info you can find here:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Comment: But I have to change date and time manually from input text, it shouldnt be readonly?

Comment: aren't you using datepicker? when you click the plugin automatically get values from the calendar/clock and throw into the input!
if you want to put time without datepicker, use "meio mask" or "masked input" plugin
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: yes datepicker,I mean users should be able to write whatever want, not only with slide bar.for example if you want to change date , when even write incorrect type it is converted to correct format. but for time it is not

Comment: hmm have you tried any mask? in which case does it convert to correct format, can you give me an example?

Comment: for example 27/07/12 from here first example
(http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ ) change
2755464/07/12 datepicker is converting  08/01/2012, like that,but ıf you want to change time, it is impossible

Comment: you could try using the onkeypress/onkeyup function on the input, get its value and treat as you need, but it will get a lot of time to fit the format you want!